# Making module dropdown field multilingual

Tags: joomla

I have a `.xml` where one of my field is this one:

Now in the backend module page, I have a dropdown called `category` with options - `category one`, `category two`. I have a custom made table with translated values for this options. My question is: How to perform actions on the drodown field options, before the rendering of the module?

Comment: You already have a [joomla.se] Stack Exchange account. Why not post your Joomla question in the dedicated community? Would you like me to request this page to be migrated to JSE?

Comment: Because there is joomla tag here as well. And there community is less active.

Comment: I understand that argument -- there is certainly more activity in Stack Overflow, but how will the JSE community become more active if new questions are posted elsewhere? This is the Chicken-or-the-Egg problem that I am trying to fix.  I find an equal amount of unanswered Joomla tagged questions here as there are unanswered questions on JSE.  If you are underwhelmed by the support offered here after some time and would like this question to be migrated, please ping me and I'll help with that. I hope you get the support that you seek.